# correct way to display image from php onto page

Tags: php, jquery

I am not getting my image correctly.  I am unsure what is happening.  First things first, the image is coming out of a mysql query.  Little confused about how to make that image ready for a ajax call?

here is how I get the image out mysql

```
    if(mysql_query("insert into Personal_Photos (Email, Pics) values('$email', '$data')"))
            {
                $query="select Pics, MAX(ID) from Personal_Photos where Email='$email'";
                $result=mysql_query($query) or die("Error: ".mysql_error());
                $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
                //$mime = 'image/yourtype';
                //$base64 = base64_encode($contents);
                //$uri = "data:$mime;base64,$base64";
                //header("Content-type: image/jpg");
                echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64'.base64_encode($row['Pics']).'"/>';
            }
```

the jquery that I use is like so

```
$('#profilepicbutton').live('change', function(){
    $("#preview").html('');
    $("#preview").html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');
        $("#registerpt3").ajaxForm({
                target: '#preview',
                success: function(data)
                {                                   
                    $("#preview").html('');
                    $("#preview").append(data);
                }
            }).submit();
 })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are missing the comma for the data URI

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,###############"/>
```

Comment: Good point.  It didn't help much, but I did in fact miss that.  I just don't get what I am doing wrong?